# Ошибка в mysql ERROR 126 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_b09_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

У меня на сервере постоянно возникает такая ошибка

> ERROR 126 (HY000) at line 1: Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_b09_0.MYI'; try to repair it.

Как ее можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите запрос, который приводит к этой ошибке, иначе помочь Вам никто не сможет.

Comment: это не запрос, эта ошибка при перезагрузке сервера mysql

Answer (score 2):

Я так предполагаю, что у вас проблема в том, что переполнен или просто очень маленький `/tmp`.

Увеличить `/tmp` (если это tmpfs) можно так:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o remount,size=1G tmpfs /tmp
```